# Android - Multiple fragment stack in each tab ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been trying to create an app that uses the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, TabLayout, and Fragments.  My goal is to have an app that functions as described below.

```
[App]-->
       -->[Tab1 Default View]-->ChildFragment-->ChildFragment
       -->[Tab2 Default View]-->ChildFragment-->ChildFragment
       -->[Tab3 Default View]-->ChildFragment-->ChildFragment
```

So, when the app loads, it would show Tab1 by default.  Tab 1 would have it's "Root" view, and when I load a new "screen" from within it, it would nest the screens inside the Tab1.  So if Tab1's title was "Tab 1" it would show that by default, but then if I click a button to load a new screen in tab 1, it would show the title as "New screen" and the back arrow would appear, which on click would take me back one level to the root view.

I've tried following the tutorial here...

https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/

However, it's FULL of errors and will not even compile in Android Studio newest version.  Can anyone provide a short and sweet example project or even a link to a working example that I can follow?

My app has always worked fine using ActivityGroup class, but since it has been deprecated since Api 13 I feel I REALLY need to update my app so it continues working in future Android versions.

Help please!?!?!

Comment: Its working for me

Comment: @Pravin - what version of Android Studio?  I'm on 2.1.2 and it is not working for me.  Can't get it to build successfully

Comment: @Pravin - are you downloading the source zip from the link on the page or are you simply working through the tutorial?

Comment: no I've done copy paste code in my project and its working fine

Comment: @Pravin, so how did you get a reference to the com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator?  How did you bring this into the project?

Comment: @Pravin, how did you import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator?

Comment: I am not importing com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator because I dont nedd

Comment: @Pravin - so what did you use in it's place?

Comment: simply create TabPageIndicator package and copy paste all classes